# Почему Python не видит атрибут, который задается при создании класса?

Tags: python

Создал класс для нанесения текста на изображение.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

class Blank():
    def __init___(self):
        self.loadImage()
        self.txt = Image.new('RGBA', self.img.size, (255,255,255,0))
        self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.txt)

    def loadImage(self):
        try:
            self.img = Image.open('sts.png').convert("RGBA")
        except IOError:
            print("Unable to load image")
            sys.exit(1)

    def setSerialNumber(self, serial_number):
        (x, y) = (900, 50)
        message = serial_number
        font_serial = ImageFont.truetype('2057.ttf', size=43)
        self.draw.text((x, y), message, fill=(200, 0, 0, 255), font=font_serial)

    def saveImage(self):
        combined = Image.alpha_composite(self.img, self.txt)
        combined.save('sts_new.png')
```

вот так его вызываю

```
   sts = Blank() 
   if request.method == 'POST':
      sts.setSerialNumber(request.form.get("serial_number"))
   sts.saveImage()
```

Но выдается ошибка

```
AttributeError: 'Blank' object has no attribute 'draw'
```

Почему он не видит этот атрибут, ведь он задается при создании класса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инициализация класса не выполняется, потому что в методе  `__init___(self)` слишком много подчеркиваний в названии, а именно - сзади три. Вот так правильно:

```
class Blank:
    def __init__(self):
```